# C# ItextSharp integrate Quicktime movie into a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, quicktime

I was wondering if it is possible to integrate a Quicktime movie into a PDF with iTextSharp or other PDF tools.  I have been able integrate images without a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Could I ask why you would want to do this?  Wouldn't it vastly limit the portability of a **P**DF?

Comment: @DanField, "portability" needs to be taken with context. If you want the most future-proof PDF then embedding a video file into a PDF that requires 3rd-party externally installed software (hopefully the OP knows this) is not "portable". However, if you are building, for instance, an approval workflow system that relies on the PDF because of things like annotations, history and signing features and one of the things that needs approval is a video then this is a very nice "portable" system.

Comment: Well, the "P" in "PDF" stands for "portable," so that's not a bad point.  I would think that something like an approval workflow system would be a web application and not rely entirely on non-standard PDFs.  Or at the very least, you might consider a plug-in to Acrobat.

Comment: Actually this is all 100% in spec and standardized, there's a whole chapter dedicated to multimedia features.

Comment: A client has requested this.  I wrote an iPhone app that sends a video to a windows server through a web service.  They are small videos.

Answer (score 3):

Is it [this](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-pdf-embed-video.htm) you are looking for?

**Edit**
*In short*

- First you have to create a movie annotation by using the `CreateScreen` method of the `PdfAnnotation` class
- You can create an movie annotation using this media types `.aiff, .au, .avi, .mid, .mov, .mp4, .mp4, .mpeg, .smil, .swf`
- Then you need to add the movie annotation to the PDF by using the `AddAnnotation` method of the `PdfWriter`

  ```
  /create a document object
  var doc = new Document();
  //output file path
  String outfile = "d:/pdfdoc.pdf";
  //get PdfWriter object
  PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(outfile, FileMode.Create));
  //open the document for writing
  doc.Open();
  //Create an instance of PdfFileSpecification
  PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, "d:/bailey.mpg", "bailey.mpg", null);
  //create and add a movie annotation to PDF document
  writer.AddAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.CreateScreen(writer, new Rectangle(200f, 700f, 400f, 800f), "Bailey", fs,"video/mpeg", true));
  //close the document
  doc.Close();
  //view the result pdf file
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outfile);
  ```

***Note***
I'm not the owner of this content, it's only a brief summary of the tutorial from the website *worldbestlearningcenter.com* (link above)

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you actually described the steps - what happens when a future user comes here and clicks a broken link?  It's fine to reference the source, but at least include the relevant API calls in the answer.

Comment: @DanField Thank you for your constructive comment. I'm a SO newbie so I'm still learning how to behave here. I hope my edited Version of my answer is a bit better.

Comment: Indeed a good job on the update. This is the kind of answers we need.

Comment: I will give this a try.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @BrianKalski I'm curious did this solve your problem?

Comment: I gave the code above a try but I wasn't able to get the video to play in the pdf.  I didn't spend a lot of time on it.  I eventually convinced the client that putting the videos in the pdf was a bad idea.  We found another solution.